# mod_rewrite with subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page called `category.php` and inside of it I have links to articles and others categories.

To open an article that is inside of a category, the code is:

```
<a href='article/". $art_id ."'> Article 1 </a>
```

To open other category that is inside of category, the code is:

```
<a href='category/". $cat_id ."'> Category 2 </a>
```

I have this code on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9]+)$ category.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1
```

`category 1` open just fine, but when I click in a link inside of category page to open an article or other category, the link turns:

```
http://www.example.com/category/article/1
http://www.example.com/category/category/2
```

Both URLs results on page not found, what is best to do to have it organized?

Something like:

```
http://www.example.com/category/1/article/1
```

Comment: The problem is not in `mod_rewrite` - it is in your links. They are relative to current path, so they should be either `<a href='/article/". $art_id ."'>` or just `<a href='". $art_id ."'>` Study - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Comment: Nice @Cheery! Solved. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes @Prix, would be better. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a relative URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```